# Imagick: наложение масок

Tags: imagick, php

Привет всем! Я пытаюсь создать простую маску накладываемую на изображение, используя библиотеку PHP Image Magick. Я создал два изображения обычный белый квадрат на прозрачном фоне и взял обычный файл jpg c обычной текстурой. 
Далее я применил следующий код...

```
  <?php
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagemagic/image/bg.jpg');
$mask = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/imagemagic/image/mask_1.png');

$width = $mask->getImageWidth();
$height = $mask->getImageHeight();

$image->resizeImage($width, $height, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

$image->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
?>
```

В итоге изображение вырезалось но так как я и хотел но фон почему то стал черным. И вопрос в следующем как сделать фон прозрачным?

Comment: Ищите инфу про альфа каналы PHP Image Magick.

Comment: а какую именно информацию искать?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо, чтобы Альфа канал был включен.
В `GD` это выглядит примерно так

```
$this->image = imagecreatefrompng($img); 
imagesavealpha($this->image,TRUE);
```